# Zombie.js, Debugging "Maximum call stack size exceeded" on client-side script

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I'm using Zombie.JS headless browser, to test an Asp.Net WebForms app (anyway I think server side technology is not important in this case).
When I trigger the post of a form (this triggers many validations) I'm getting a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" without any stack-trace.
The is thrown when evaluating in the headless browser context one of the .Net functions that triggers the form submit (inside a function named WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()).
So the error is coming from a separated V8 context, ie. the simulated browser.
So I can't use node-inspector to debug that (AFAIK).

Of course this error is not ocurring when using other real browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox).

Is there any way I can get a clue of what is causing the error? getting a stack trace? can I debug code running in this separated v8 context?

(I can't add console.log() everywhere around the client-side javascript code, as it's generated by the .Net Framework (and it's ugly, includes client-side validations of the form))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually this is the result of a recursive function call, though we would need to see some of your code.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that it's not my code, it's M$ code, Asp.Net generated function named WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(), I known that internally it triggers validations done with MsAjax.
I can copy the 9E+90 lines of code of MsAjax, but I don't think it will help you :P.
Also note that this problem doesn't exists in any other real browser I use it.
I know is difficult to help me with this, but I was expecting some way to get inside the browser execution context, or at least get a stack trace for the error.

Comment: @Benja if you punch zombie js to start the new v8 context with a debugger attached you can debug it.

Comment: Is it posible? The context is create by zombie.js internally, AFAIK it uses a library named contextify https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify , but I have no idea of how can I attach a debugger to that.